# How to get clean URLs from subfolders with static html files

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm looking for a way to rewrite my .htaccess in order to archive a clean url structure. Currently my folder structure is like this

```
example.com/index.html
example.com/pages/jobs.html 
example.com/pages/disclaimer.html
```

I want to hide the "pages" folder in the URL to make it more clean and SEO friendly but keep the structure on the server itself. So the desired result would be

```
example.com/
example.com/jobs/ 
example.com/disclaimer/
```

I tried several ways and none seemed to be working. I hope someone can help.

Best,
Martin